# Split or tokenise a java String using a substring as delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

How to split or tokenise a String in java not based on regex but based on a substring?

```
String str = "{A={111={i=[a,b,c],ii=[e,f]}, 222={iii=[a,e]}}, B={333={i= [b,c]}}};
```

Now I want to tokenise or split the string based on substring "}}," and not regex "}},".

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: Also mention the desired output

Comment: @DamCx can't you ask quietly the user if he has done something ? Intsead of using multiple agressive and useless "?" ?

Comment: [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

Comment: Reason we look to Stackoverflow and other sites such as this is because we don't have time to try out all possibilities while coding a huge program. And sometimes simplest of things don't strike. It is not that I did not try, but I am facing acute shortage of time. I want to complete my project asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [`String.split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function specifies that it takes a regular expression as a parameter, that does not stop you from escaping any special characters and splitting on a literal string.

To escape special characters in a regular expression, you can make use of the [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) function, or you can escape the individual characters using backslashes `\\`:

```
String escapedStr = Pattern.quote("}},");

String alternativeEscapedStr = "\\}\\},";
```

For the example you have provided however, you shouldn't need to escape anything:

```
String str = "{A={111={i=[a,b,c],ii=[e,f]}, 222={iii=[a,e]}}, B={333={i= [b,c]}}}";

String[] splitStr = str.split(Pattern.quote("}},"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitStr));

String[] splitStr2 = str.split("}},");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitStr2));
```

Output:

```
[{A={111={i=[a,b,c],ii=[e,f]}, 222={iii=[a,e],  B={333={i= [b,c]}}}]
[{A={111={i=[a,b,c],ii=[e,f]}, 222={iii=[a,e],  B={333={i= [b,c]}}}]
```

Comment: Thank You for detailed explanation! This also worked. StringTokeniser was using regex, and explanation of split api is that it takes regex, that was what was confusing.

Comment: @user3322178 You're welcome, please accept an answer if your problem has been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "{A={111={i=[a,b,c],ii=[e,f]}, 222={iii=[a,e]}}, B={333={i= [b,c]}}}";
String[] split = str.trim().split("}},");
Arrays.stream(split).forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: @user3322178 pleasure